# Python + Pandas : Problem reading json - strange structure

Tags: python, json, pandas

We have a json with the following structure, of course, I read it without any problems, only everything goes in one line and the columns have a name associated with task_id

```
{
  "76010511": {
    "task_id": "76010511",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "assigned_by": "1796633",
    "name": "praca",
    "external_task_id": null,
    "external_parent_id": null,
    "level": "1",
    "archived": "0",
    "tags": "",
    "budgeted": "0",
    "budget_unit": "",
    "root_group_id": "508916",
    "billable": "1",
    "note": null,
    "public_hash": null,
    "add_date": "2020-09-23 06:49:29",
    "modify_time": null,
    "color": "#68E3B1",
    "users": {
      "1796633": {
        "user_id": "1796633",
        "role_id": "1"
      }
    },
    "user_access_type": 4
  },
  "76010692": {
    "task_id": "76010692",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "assigned_by": "1796633",
    "name": "nowe",
    "external_task_id": null,
    "external_parent_id": null,
    "level": "1",
    "archived": "0",
    "tags": "",
    "budgeted": "0",
    "budget_unit": "",
    "root_group_id": "508916",
    "billable": "1",
    "note": null,
    "public_hash": null,
    "add_date": "2020-09-23 07:29:05",
    "modify_time": null,
    "color": "#F9C947",
    "users": {
      "1796633": {
        "user_id": "1796633",
        "role_id": "1"
      }
    },
    "user_access_type": 4
  },
  "76010693": {
    "task_id": "76010693",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "assigned_by": "1796633",
    "name": "inne",
    "external_task_id": null,
    "external_parent_id": null,
    "level": "1",
    "archived": "0",
    "tags": "",
    "budgeted": "0",
    "budget_unit": "",
    "root_group_id": "508916",
    "billable": "1",
    "note": null,
    "public_hash": null,
    "add_date": "2020-09-23 07:29:12",
    "modify_time": null,
    "color": "#725E5E",
    "users": {
      "1796633": {
        "user_id": "1796633",
        "role_id": "1"
      }
    },
    "user_access_type": 4
  }
}
```

Below the query code, very simple, I tried in various ways, unfortunately the result is still the same

```
with o.urlopen(json_link) as jfile_tc:
    dane_tc_0 = json.load(jfile_tc)
    dane_tc_all = json_normalize(dane_tc_0)
dane_tc_all
```

I would like to do this in the form of a table :

```
task_id;parent_id;assigned_by;name;external_task_id;external_parent_id;root_group_id;billable;note;public_hash;add_date;modify_time;user_access_type;user_id;role_id
76010511;0;1796633;praca;None;None;508916;1;None;None;23.09.2020;None;4;1796633;1
76010511;0;1796633;praca;None;None;508916;1;None;None;23.09.2020;None;4;1796631;2
```

Am I able to do this with json_normalize, or better something else to bring it to this look?
I'm running out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `orient='index'`:

```python
import pandas as pd

pd.read_json(json_link, orient='index', convert_axes=False)
```

```
           task_id  parent_id  assigned_by   name  external_task_id  \
76010511  76010511          0      1796633  praca               NaN   
76010692  76010692          0      1796633   nowe               NaN   
76010693  76010693          0      1796633   inne               NaN   

          external_parent_id  level  archived tags  budgeted budget_unit  \
76010511                 NaN      1         0              0               
76010692                 NaN      1         0              0               
76010693                 NaN      1         0              0               

          root_group_id  billable  note  public_hash             add_date  \
76010511         508916         1   NaN          NaN  2020-09-23 06:49:29   
76010692         508916         1   NaN          NaN  2020-09-23 07:29:05   
76010693         508916         1   NaN          NaN  2020-09-23 07:29:12   

         modify_time    color  \
76010511         NaT  #68E3B1   
76010692         NaT  #F9C947   
76010693         NaT  #725E5E   

                                                      users  user_access_type  
76010511  {'1796633': {'user_id': '1796633', 'role_id': ...                 4  
76010692  {'1796633': {'user_id': '1796633', 'role_id': ...                 4  
76010693  {'1796633': {'user_id': '1796633', 'role_id': ...                 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I was sticking to "json_normalize"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following ?

a) your remove the "null" values
b) you pass your json, let's call it data, to a pd df with :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(data)
new_df = df.transpose()
```

the data variable :

```
data =  {'76010511': {'task_id': '76010511', 'parent_id': '0', 'assigned_by': '1796633', 'name': 'praca', 'external_task_id': 'null', 'external_parent_id': 'null', 'level': '1', 'archived': '0', 'tags': '', 'budgeted': '0', 'budget_unit': '', 'root_group_id': '508916', 'billable': '1', 'note': 'null', 'public_hash': 'null', 'add_date': '2020-09-23 06:49:29', 'modify_time': 'null', 'color': '#68E3B1', 'users': {'1796633': {'user_id': '1796633', 'role_id': '1'}}, 'user_access_type': 4}, '76010692': {'task_id': '76010692', 'parent_id': '0', 'assigned_by': '1796633', 'name': 'nowe', 'external_task_id': 'null', 'external_parent_id': 'null', 'level': '1', 'archived': '0', 'tags': '', 'budgeted': '0', 'budget_unit': '', 'root_group_id': '508916', 'billable': '1', 'note': 'null', 'public_hash': 'null', 'add_date': '2020-09-23 07:29:05', 'modify_time': 'null', 'color': '#F9C947', 'users': {'1796633': {'user_id': '1796633', 'role_id': '1'}}, 'user_access_type': 4}, '76010693': {'task_id': '76010693', 'parent_id': '0', 'assigned_by': '1796633', 'name': 'inne', 'external_task_id': 'null', 'external_parent_id': 'null', 'level': '1', 'archived': '0', 'tags': '', 'budgeted': '0', 'budget_unit': '', 'root_group_id': '508916', 'billable': '1', 'note': 'null', 'public_hash': 'null', 'add_date': '2020-09-23 07:29:12', 'modify_time': 'null', 'color': '#725E5E', 'users': {'1796633': {'user_id': '1796633', 'role_id': '1'}}, 'user_access_type': 4}}

import json
data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.
I mainly tried with "json_normalize" and always got the result in one line

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, and your code is not runnable. What exactly did you try so far? What exactly did you get? Why exactly is it wrong? What exactly do you want to get?

I see you have a history of asking for help processing many different JSON objects. My advice would be to stop asking others for magic solutions, and simply think through each problem slowly, follow your data step-by-step, check closely for bugs, and check what's coming in and out at each step.

Nonetheless, the question asks for a Pandas solution, and there is an extremely easy solution here, so here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json('your_filename.json', orient='index').set_index('task_id')
```

Please don't just copy-paste this and ask another question later, but read the documentation for this function, understand what it does, what is the reason for `orient='index'`, and so on. A JSON structure can many have layers of depth and can not always be logically transformed to a simple table, you have to think a bit more carefully about exactly what it is you want in each case.